# Rails link_to :format => :xlsx not generating link to .xlsx path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I hit this url: `http://localhost:3000/reports/action.xlsx` it shows a generated xlsx file.

If I have a `link_to` like this:

```rb
<%= link_to 'Export to Excel', reports_affirmative_action_path, :format => :xlsx %>
```

It generates a link to this page:
`http://localhost:3000/reports/action`

Why does my link_to with `:format => :xlsx` not link to the correct path?

Comment: What does your controller code look like for this. Within the respond block for this particular action have you got? Furthermore are you trying to export some files as a `.xsl`?

Comment: Controller is irrelevant because directly hitting the url works. But I do have a format.xlsx in my respond_to block.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your `link_to` and `path` are slightly off. You want

```
<%= link_to('Export to Excel', reports_affirmative_action_path(format: :xlsx)) %>
```

Where the format is an argument to the `path` helper, not `link_to`.

Answer (score -3):

**Works for me**
    <%= link_to('Export to Excel',  reports_affirmative_action_path(:format => :xls)) %>

**Use :xls instead of :xlsx**