# Export data to file CSV on Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I'm trying export data using active record and csv class, but I dont have the file generated can help see me code.

when i click export does not open a dialog to download from csv am i missing something?

**My Controller**

```
def export_csv
    @contact = Contacts.find_by_sql("select * from contacts_list limit 10")
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.csv { send_data @contact.as_csv }
     end
  end
```

**My Model**

```
def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id name mail}

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |contact|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| contact.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

**My View**

```
<%= link_to( 'Export CSV' ,{ :controller => :company, :action => :export_csv, format: "csv"}, { :class => "btn-ex" } ) %>
```

**Console Ouput**

```
Started GET "/company/export_cs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-12-17 11:31:26 -0200
Processing by CompanyController#export_cs as HTML
```

only this nothing more no errors no messages warnings.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when i click export does not open a dialog to download from csv am i missing something?

Comment: After clicking on the link go to your web server console and copy the request and response info. Add it to your question, don't paste it in the comments.

Comment: @Beartech updated post dialog is not open to save csv file..

Comment: @mrzasa updated post see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to( 'Export' ,{ :controller => :company, :action => :export_csv, format: 'csv', :company_id => @company.id}, { :class => "btn-edit" } ) %>
```

Thanks Guys, workperfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate the URL for the link in a different way - using URL helper, not controller/action params:

```
<%= link_to( 'Export CSV', companies_export_csv_path(format: "csv", { :class => "btn-ex" } ) %>
```

See also: [Rails link_to :format => :xlsx not generating link to .xlsx path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043702/rails-link-to-format-xlsx-not-generating-link-to-xlsx-path)

Comment: Small correction. Right side bracket is missing. This can be written as below
`<%= link_to 'Export CSV', companies_export_csv_path(format: "csv"), { :class => "btn-ex" } %>`